# sensitivity analysis (mean of multiple simulations) in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I have several indexes such as mean and standard deviation of variables.

After 500 ticks, the model stops.

I want to simulate this model, for instance, 100 times and plot the mean and CI of indexes.

Instead of using python or R, is there any way to do this in netlogo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use BehaviorSpace to run your model 100 times, saving the results you want to a file-system file, then have a different netlogo program ( or proocedure ) read in the data and plot it.  Here's a sample writing part that computes mean and standard deviation of a run of numbers and after ten ticks stops.

```
globals [ delist demean destd fname ]

to setup
  clear-all
  set fname "myfile.txt"
  set delist []
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  if ( ticks >= 10 ) [
    ;; show delist
    set demean mean delist;
    set destd standard-deviation delist;
    export-data
    ;;print (word "mean = " demean " stdev= " destd )
    stop
  ]
  set delist lput random 100 delist
  tick
end

to export-data
  if not (file-exists? fname ) [
    file-open fname
    file-print ( word "mean stdev" );
    file-flush
    file-close
  ]
  
  file-open fname
  file-print ( word  demean " " destd  )
  file-flush
  file-close
end

to clear-file
 if  (file-exists? fname ) [
    file-delete fname
  ]
end
```

here's sample code reading the above myfile.txt in and plotting it.
Assume a plot widget reporting  demean and destd

```
globals [ delist demean destd fname ]

to setup
  clear-all
  set fname "myfile.txt"
  print " This file begins as follows:"
  set delist []
    ifelse   (file-exists? fname ) [
      file-open fname
      if  not file-at-end? 
       [ let str file-read-line 
         print str
      ]
    ]
  [  print " expected file doesn't exits " ]

  reset-ticks
end

to go
  if file-at-end? [ print "Data has been all read."  file-close stop]
  set demean file-read 
  set destd file-read  
  print (word "mean = " demean " ,  std-dev = " destd )
  tick
end
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped me a lot to report the final numbers. But what I want to is to draw plots such as this. https://images.app.goo.gl/8rKuFKovEKERpf457 (Song, H., & Boomgaarden, H. G. (2017). Dynamic spirals put to test: An agent-based model of reinforcing spirals between selective exposure, interpersonal networks, and attitude polarization. Journal of Communication, 67(2), 256-281.)

Comment: Instead of using NetLogo itself to make plots of BehaviorSpace experiment results, I would suggest using another tool, any graphing tool that can read CSV files, for example Excel.

Comment: They actually had a more complex problem -- as the plots they link to show -- they wanted to get output of a variable each tick, then after behavior space compute for each tick mean and confidence interval, and plot that with fancy plot.    Clearly if doing that sort of thing a lot, learning R for aggregation and fancy publication quality plots is worth it.  Anyway I answered with code in the netlogo google groups, or am about to, so I'd call this closed.